# Using the correct third party 32bit or 64bit assembly

Tags: visual-studio, x86, project-management, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

We have a decent size project in Visual Studios 2010 that needs to be built for 32bit and 64bit machines. Simple enough, however, we rely on a third part library for certain functionality and this third party library has a 32-bit version and a 64-bit version.

Now, If i was to build a 32-bit version of this project, I would obviously want to reference the 32-bit version of the third party's library, and the same goes for when building the 64-bit version.

How exactly is the best way to go about doing this in Visual Studios without having to switch between 32-bit and 64-bit every time I do a build?

Comment: Possible solutions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469467/how-to-distribute-both-32-and-64-bit-versions-of-the-library

Comment: It doesn't matter much for a managed project, it isn't clear if it is.  For a C++ project it is simple, every configuration has its own settings.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make different configurations and each configuration will reference it's version, when you build, you just choose the 32 or 64 configuration.

[image]